# Naming convention for Object Ownership in Methods

Tags: c++, oop, naming-conventions

Is there a way to code into the signature of a method, whether the object owner-ship changes or not? In Getter() and Setter() which take or return pointers, you never know if the object ownership changes or not.

What do you think about:

```
// Uses pConfiguration or creates its own copy - the ownership is un-touched
void ContainerClass:SetConfiguration( const Configuration* pConfiguration ) {}
// Takes the ownership of pConfiguration (and deletes it in the destructor)
void ContainerClass:PutConfiguration( Configuration* pConfiguration ) {}
// Returns a 'reference' and keeps the ownership (you must not delete it)
const Configuration* ContainerClass::GetConfiguration() {}
// Returns a _new_ object and transfers the ownership to you
Configuration* ContainerClass::TakeConfiguration() {}
```

So is Set() vs. Put() and Get() vs. Take() a way to code it, or would you use the type (const vs. non-const) - or do you know it from the context?

Best Regards,

Charly

Comment: Have you checked about smart pointers? It will avoid these types of problems.

Comment: Hmmm... it solves the delete problem... but it still says nothing about the object ownership. I have to think about - if it solves all my problems :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of identifying in an interface that ownership is not changed is by not using pointers. Prefer references to pointers:

```
// Does not take ownership
void ContainerClass::SetConfiguration( const Configuration& config ) {}

// Does not release ownership
const Configuration& ContainerClass::getConfiguration() const {}
```

When you need to actually transfer ownership of memory it is better documenting it by names. If you really feel the crave to make it explicit in the signature, use the good-old `std::auto_ptr`:

```
void ContainerClass::SetConfiguration( std::auto_ptr<Configuration> cfg );
std::auto_ptr<Configuration> ContainerClass::CopyConfiguration() const;
```

The `std::auto_ptr` has the weird property that *copy* actually means *transfer the ownership*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Write good documentation and comments (you can use doxygen)
2. In Qt where functions often play with ownership methods called for example `itemAt` and `takeAt` and `addXXX` always transfer ownership which is reflected in documentation. So you can use `get()` / `take()` and `set()` / `put()`. Anyway, good docs is always helpful, even your functions names are self-explained.

Comment: Yes, good documentation is nothing to discuss about. But having a naming convention in the signature, you would have this information in your code - and not in another header.

Comment: You cannot say *Qt* and *good documentation* in the same sentence. Qt's documentation is pretty much lacking, and there is no (documented) convention on function signatures either. Does [QBoxLayout::addWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) transfer ownership of its argument? Take a guess. Read the documentation. Read the source code. Take note, at which point you mumble *"wtf!?"*. And stop using Qt as an example of good documentation. If the documentation makes you read the source code, something is very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when using pointers, there is no "ownership" to begin
with, so there's no issue of it changing.  But design is the key; the
role of the class should make clear its relationship with the object
pointed to.  At a higher level than ownership or whatever.  And that
relationship, in turn, determines what it will do with the object.

For the exceptional cases where ownership is relevant, `std::auto_ptr`
is the standard way of expressing transfer.  It's an absolute transfer,
though; if the parameter has a type `std::auto_ptr`, then the caller
cannot even access the object once he's called the function.  (I've
found this very effective in threading scenarios.  It does make sense
for an object to be owned by a specific thread, at any given time, and
that no other thread can access it, and `std::auto_ptr` expresses this
very clearly and effectively.)